# PHP Injection in MySQL works when hardcoded

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following SQL query that I can successfully test in Workbench:

```
        $interviewInfo = $this->db->fetchAll("
            SELECT 
                c.s,
                c.t,
                i.u,
                i.v,
                qa.w,
                i.x
            FROM
                XXX AS i,
                YYY as ip,
                ZZZ AS qa,
                BBB AS c
            WHERE
                c.s = :CompanyId AND ip.r = i.Id
                    AND i.s = c.s
                    AND ip.t = qa.p
                    AND i.h > 0
            ORDER BY i.q DESC
            LIMIT 3", array("CompanyId"=>$companyId));
```

But with the associative array dependency injection in my SQL statement, it returns an empty array.

I have tried directly inserting CompanyId in place of `:CompanyId` and then it works.

I have no idea what is going on here because there is:

1. No error from MySQL.
2. The query is correct and I can verify that.
3. I can also verify `CompanyId` exists and is a valid integer.

Comment: What database wrapper are you using?

Comment: @Nick We are using PHP's `PDO` as a wrapper around MySQL transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) works. You must first [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) your query, then [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) it, and then you can call `fetchAll` to get the results. Something like this should work:

```
$stmt = $this->db-prepare("SELECT 
                c.s,
                c.t,
                i.u,
                i.v,
                qa.w,
                i.x
            FROM
                XXX AS i,
                YYY as ip,
                ZZZ AS qa,
                BBB AS c
            WHERE
                c.s = :CompanyId AND ip.r = i.Id
                    AND i.s = c.s
                    AND ip.t = qa.p
                    AND i.h > 0
            ORDER BY i.q DESC
            LIMIT 3");
$stmt->execute(array("CompanyId"=>$companyId));
$interviewInfo = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Note that you should also check that the `prepare` and `execute` statements succeeded by checking that `$stmt` is not `false` and that `execute` does not return false.